# Create CSV from multidimensional array with fputcsv

Tags: php, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, fputcsv

I'm trying to get a multidimensional array into a csv file. data in the array is as such:

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 1111
        [name] => Alcatel One Touch Idol 2
        [keyword] => alcatel-one-touch-idol-2
        [options] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [price] => 54.0000
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [price] => 42.0000
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [price] => 10.0000
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [price] => 
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [price] => 
                    )

                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [price] => 
                    )

                [6] => Array
                    (
                        [price] => 
                    )

                [7] => Array
                    (
                        [price] => 
                    )

                [8] => Array
                    (
                        [price] => 
                    )

                [9] => Array
                    (
                        [price] => 
                    )

            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (...... etc)
```

I get all of the top level data, but then once it reaches the options array, i get  `Array to string conversion` errors. So i have two issue, i firstly need to see why i am getting this error, and then i need to fputcsv all of this information on one line per product.

So far i have this to parse the array into a csv:

```
$output = fopen("php://output",'w') or die("Can't open php://output");
            header("Content-Type:application/csv"); 
            header("Content-  Disposition:attachment;filename=product_catalog.csv"); 
            $first_line = explode(",", $first_line);
            fputcsv($output, $first_line);
            foreach($csv as $file) {
                fputcsv($output, $file);
            }
            fclose($output) or die("Can't close php://output");
```

If anyone could help me i'd really appreciate that.
regards.

Comment: Does it *have* to be CSV? Could the receiving side handle JSON instead? Using JSON would mean that the structure of the array would be kept (no flattening) and the recreation of the data is easier

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would suggest to flatten each array first:

```
foreach ($csv as $file) {
    $result = [];
    array_walk_recursive($file, function($item) use (&$result) {
        $result[] = $item;
    });
    fputcsv($output, $result);
}
```

In each iteration it would create an array like this:

```
[1111, 'Alcatel One Touch Idol 2', 'alcatel-one-touch-idol-2', 54, 42, ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($data as $line) {
    foreach($line as $array){
        foreach($array as $result){
            fputcsv($f,$result,",");
        }
    }
}
```

i know its an old question but you could also use this