# PHP convert json into csv with sub array

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

I was creating php code to convert the below json to csv

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [DESC] => bla bal bal
                    [SOLD] => 0
                    [contact_no] => 1234
                    [title] =>  Hiiiii
                    [price] => 10900
                    [big_image] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => http://example.com/images/user_adv/14.jpg
                            [1] => http://example.com/images/user_adv/15.jpg
                        )

                    [small_image] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => http://example.com/images/user_adv/small/14.jpg
                            [1] => http://example.com/images/user_adv/small/15.jpg
                        )

                    [tpe] => user
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [DESC] => fo fo fof ofof
                    [SOLD] => 0
                    [contact_no] => 234522
                    [title] => Hellooooo sddf
                    [price] => 0
                    [big_image] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => http://example.com/images/user_adv/154.jpg
                            [1] => http://example.com/images/user_adv/144.jpg
                            [2] => http://example.com/images/user_adv/147.jpg
                        )

                    [small_image] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => http://example.com/images/user_adv/small/154.jpg
                            [1] => http://example.com/images/user_adv/small/144.jpg
                            [2] => http://example.com/images/user_adv/small/147.jpg
                        )

                    [tpe] => user
                )

        )

    [pis] => 3
    [totals] => 23
    [curpage] => 1
    [total_ads] => 71
)
```

I've been using the below code to export it to .csv

```
$fp = fopen("output.csv","w");

foreach ($json['data'] as $fields) {
fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
```

I can convert it fine, but I face a small issue that the sub array which is big_image & small_image is NOT appearing in the output file .csv (the row is empty)

```
       [big_image] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => http://example.com/images/user_adv/154.jpg
                            [1] => http://example.com/images/user_adv/144.jpg
                            [2] => http://example.com/images/user_adv/147.jpg
                        )

                    [small_image] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => http://example.com/images/user_adv/small/154.jpg
                            [1] => http://example.com/images/user_adv/small/144.jpg
                            [2] => http://example.com/images/user_adv/small/147.jpg
                        )
```

By the way, if I replace:

```
foreach ($json['data'] as $fields) {
```

with

```
foreach ($json['data'][0] as $fields) {
```

I get the link pictures as output, so I need to merge them as one output

```
  foreach ($json['data'] as $fields) {
  foreach ($json['data'][0] as $fields2) {
```

edit :

here the output
[image: 1]

edit 2 :

i expect the output something like that

[image: 2]

Comment: It sounds like you need to test if `is_array()`, and if so, then to loop over those, ie. `if(is_array($fields)){ foreach($fields as $fields2) { fputcsv($fp, $fields2); } else {fputcsv($fp, $fields); }`

Comment: posibly like this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/28323742/4262684 ?

Comment: I've following the link and change my code as below `$fp = fopen("output.csv","w");
foreach ($json as $fields) {
    $iresult = [];
    array_walk_recursive($fields, function($item) use (&$iresult) {
        $iresult[] = $item;
    });
    fputcsv($fp, $iresult);
}
` now is working but they all in one line ,, i guess need little edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a function to make sure those nested arrays are made flat. You can create a utility function for that, like this:

```
function array_flatten ($nonFlat) {
    $flat = array();
    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
            new RecursiveArrayIterator($nonFlat)) as $k=>$v) {
        $flat[$k] = $v;
    }
    return $flat;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
$fp = fopen("output.csv","w");
foreach ($json['data'] as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, array_flatten($fields));
}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: thank you for your effort , actually I've added the first code but i got like warning `PHP Warning:  fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in /var/www/mycall.php on line 36` but is writing in output.csv file only the image path either small & big ... for the second code i got error `PHP Warning:  fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in /var/www/mycall.php on line 37` with nothing in output.csv file.. I also wondering why i need to put test array for arrays image small & big , since it should be their ?

Comment: seems is working but still face little issue in the output  of link  pictures ... each link of pictures is have one row so looks like bad , need to make each group of pics on one row.

Comment: You mean column, not row, right? Can you provide the expected output in your question?

Comment: Do you need all image urls, or would the first one be enough. Because putting them together in one column....  I am not sure how you would format that.

Comment: not all images urls, mean each array have group for image urls.. i have update my question and add the output pic

Comment: That seems to be the output like my answer would produce: I see three columns, each with an image URL. I don't understand what you want.