# How to convert subarray json to CSV file?

Tags: php, json, csv

I'd like to convert JSON to CSV file.
Here's my PHP code :

```
<?php
$response = '[{
    "field1": "vala1",
    "field2": "vala2",
    "field3": "vala3",
    "field4": [{
        "field4a": "vala4-1",
        "field4b": "vala4-2",
        "field4c": "vala4-3"
    }]
}, {
    "field1": "valb1",
    "field2": "valb2",
    "field3": "valb3",
    "field4": [{
        "field4a": "valb4-1",
        "field4b": "valb4-2",
        "field4c": "valb4-3"
    }]
}]';

$list = json_decode($response, true);
$fp = fopen('test_json.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields, ';');
}

fclose($fp); 
?>
```

But, I get this notice:

> Array to string conversion

In my CSV file I get **Array** value in fourth column.

Here's expected output:

```
vala1;vala2;vala3;vala4-1,vala4-2,vala4-3
valb1;valb2;valb3;valb4-1,valb4-2,valb4-3
```

I can get expected value if I use this code :

```
    echo $fields['field1'] . ';' . $fields['field2'] . ';' . $fields['field3'] . ';' . $fields['field4'][0]['field4a'] . ',' . $fields['field4'][0]['field4b'] . ',' . $fields['field4'][0]['field4c'] . '<br>';
```

But it's not flexible..
So, how to convert subarray json to CSV file that works even if I add many fields in JSON file?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: you're doing a single loop, which means you `$fields` are the child arrays, which you then try to dump out as a string. you need multiple loops.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP convert json into csv with sub array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34244197/php-convert-json-into-csv-with-sub-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: I was an idiot and wasn't thinking. The correct answer should be as so:

```
foreach ($list as $fields) {
    $flatFields = [];
    foreach ($fields as $value) {
        $newValue = $value;
        if (isset($value[0]) && is_array($value[0])) {
            $newValue = implode(',', $value[0]);
        }
        $flatFields[] = $newValue;
    }
    fputcsv($fp, $flatFields, ';');
}
```

Haven't tested yet but should be fine. If, however, your subarrays *also* contain subarrays, you'll need a recursive function to handle it - let me know and I'll update this answer.

Comment: Thanks Sworrub for your response, but I get this error : `fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array`

Comment: Thanks again, but I get this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$value' (T_VARIABLE) `. I'm very sorry... Thanks :)

Comment: Oops, missed a comma, should be `$newValue = implode(',', $value);` I'll actually run the code before I make the edit this time to make sure I've not missed anything else :P

Comment: I missed something else too, didn't realise your subarrays were JSON objects themselves so I've had to use `$value[0]` to get those objects instead. Check the edit, I've ran it now and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
...
    $list = json_decode($response, true);
    $fp = fopen('test_json.csv', 'w');

    foreach ($list as $fields) {
        $fields['field4'] = implode(',',$fields['field4']);
        fputcsv($fp, $fields, ';');
    }

    fclose($fp);
```

Comment: This will only work if the subarrays are always in field4, I'm guessing that this is not always the case. Also, it should be $fields['field4'][0] due to the structure of his JSON - I made this mistake in my answer too.